# Completely replace the Care Coordinator role throughout

Tags: health-cloud

Is it possible to entirely relabel/replace the Care Coordinator role in Health Cloud?

It is the standard out-the-box role name for the primary assigned internal care person to the Patient.

I have tried cloning and changing the value on the Custom Metadata record, and adding a new one. As well as various combinations of adding the new desired value and removing the old in the Case Team role values. Including adding the new role to the Assigned To picklist on Care Plan Template Task object, and editing all template tasks to assign to the new role rather than Care Coordinator.

Each attempted combination results in different blockers. Either, "you must add Care Coordinator" on the Lead to Patient conversion steps, or on the Apply Care Plan steps.

Overriding the Custom label: Field_Label_Care_Coordinator (Care Coordinator label: "Care Coordinator") doesn't seem to change anything.

Documentation I have used:
[Customize Care Team Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_customize_delivered_roles.htm&type=5)
[Create Roles for Care Team Members](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_care_team_roles.htm&type=5)
[Customize Health Cloud Labels](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_customize_labels.htm&type=5)